# How to crawling a site using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, python, web-crawler

I'm using python 3.x and exercising crawling using Beautifulsoap

I want to learn how to crawling site using JAVASCRIPT

for example)

```
<a id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btnDown"
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDown','')">
<img src="/images/common/icon/icrobat.gif" alt="emememem"></a>

<a href="javascript:fn_FileDownLoad('NewsLetter/Attach/2016/12/KIPF_161111.pdf',
'_KIPF_161111.pdf');">KIPF_161111.pdf</a>
```

In this,

usually, I expect the

```
a href="/alal/blablabla.pdf"
```

So, I used the URL and then I got pdf files.

But, In first code

```
"href = javascript:__doPostBack("ct100$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnDown','')"

href="javascript:fn_FileDownLoad('NewsLetter/Attach/2016/12/KIPF_161111.pdf',
'_KIPF_161111.pdf');">KIPF_161111.pdf</a>
```

Where is url??

I thought that I got selenium. So, If I use the a ~~~.click(), I will get the url about pdf file I want

for example

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:\phantomjs.exe")
driver.get("http://blablablablablabla.html")
submitButton.click()
```

right??

I'm very confused.

Comment: there is a method called `get_attribute()` in selenium, you can use it to get the html code of a dynamic page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the method you need: `get_attribute()`

the usage is like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("your phantomjs path")
driver.get("your target url")

#firstly locate the block you need by specifying the css attribute,
#then get its inner HTML code
html = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('...').get_attribute('innerHTML')

#or you can locate the block by the id attribute
html = driver.find_element_by_id('...').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```